# problem with drupal_http_build_query output

Tags: 7, database, http-request

am using drupal_http_build_query and have part of my code as follows:

```
$or = db_or();
$or->condition('cid',$fField1);
$or->condition('cid',$fField2);
$or->condition('cid',$fField3);
$or->condition('cid',$fField4);
$or->condition('cid',$fField5);
$or->condition('cid',$fField6);
$or->condition('cid',$fField7);
$or->condition('cid',$fField8);

$querydata  = db_select('webform_submitted_data', 'wsd')
  ->fields('wsd',array('data'))
  ->condition('nid', $nodeID, '=')
  ->condition('sid', $sID, '=')         
  ->condition($or)
  ->execute()
  ->fetchAll();


$result = array();
$i = 1;
foreach ($querydata as $qvalue) {
    $key = 'mapField'.$i;
    $result[] = array($$key => $qvalue->data);
    $i++;
}

$post_data = drupal_http_build_query($result,'', '&');
```

When printing the `$post_data` variable value, am getting something like this:
`name=john&1[address]=street1&2[phone]=123456789`

Notice the `1[]` and `2[]` after the `&`in the printed value. Any fix to remove these so that I get `name=john&address=street1&phone=123456789`?

Comment: As side note, `drupal_http_build_query()` only uses two parameters, not three; since you are using the default value for the second one, you can simply use `drupal_http_build_query($result)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting that result because you build `$result` as an array whose values are array. Since `drupal_http_build_query()` contains the following code, the result you obtain is by design.

```
  foreach ($query as $key => $value) {
    $key = ($parent ? $parent . '[' . rawurlencode($key) . ']' : rawurlencode($key));

    // Recurse into children.
    if (is_array($value)) {
      $params [] = drupal_http_build_query($value, $key);
    }
    // If a query parameter value is NULL, only append its key.
    elseif (!isset($value)) {
      $params [] = $key;
    }
    else {
      // For better readability of paths in query strings, we decode slashes.
      $params [] = $key . '=' . str_replace('%2F', '/', rawurlencode($value));
    }
  }
```

You should change the code to the following one.

```
foreach ($querydata as $qvalue) {
  $key = 'mapField' . $i;
    $result[$$key] = $qvalue->data;
    $i++;
}
```